# Show information in "Right detail" of UITableViewCell

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have an UITableViewController with some static cell. Each cell has a right detail style. By touching on one of this I go to the next controller. In the next controller I have two cells with checkmarks.

Question: How can I see info at "right detail" by touching only one cell at NEXT controller?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please clarify what you mean by "right detail style" and "right detail". Also we won't ever understand what "How can I see info at right detail" will mean. What exactly do you want to display? And where do you want to display it????

Comment: @Julian as you know I can make UITableViewCell with right detail style. I want to see info on this right detail style which I choose by touching only one cell at NEXT controller

Comment: Do you mean the accessoryType? Or the accessoryView?

Comment: @Julian I mean accessoryType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments above I got a rudimentarily idea of what you want to achieve. You want to use `[cell setAccessoryView:aView];` instead of `setAccessoryType`.

Corresponding on how much information you want to display (if it's either just a little image or a huge textView) there are better choices.

I'd recommend creating a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. These can be layouted in IB and you can quite easily connect IBOutlets and put custom methods and properties on it:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MUTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = (MUTableViewCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MUTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [cell setStoredInfoText:[inforSourceArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MUTableViewCell *cell = (MUTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell callYourCustomMethod];
    [cell setInfoFieldText:@"my informational text"];
    // or either display the information you set later to the cell in -cellForRowAtIndexPath
    [cell setInfoFieldText:[cell storedInfoText]];
    // you can also merge the above methods to a method called displayInfo which then gets the storedText property internally:
    [cell displayInfo];
}


MUTableViewCell.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *storedInfoText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
- (void)setInfoFieldText:(NSString *)text;
- (void)displayInfo;

MUTableViewCell.m
- (void)setInfoFieldText:(NSString *)text {
    [_label setText:text];
}
- (void)displayInfo {
    [_label setText:_storedInfoText];
}
```